# How to size a label to take full width of a grid cell and make it center

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a **Grid WPF** control in **C#** and I want to make a **label** to take the full width and height of the grid cell it is into.

The text should increase in size depending on the cell width/height (available size) and the content should be vertically/horizontally centered.

Is there a way to do it?

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Label Content="Text 1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <Label Content="Text 2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Both of the answers below aren't going to do what you're looking for. If you want the text to grow it's still going to be restricted by the FontSize set on the control. An easy thing you could do however is place that content in a `ViewBox` and have it handle the scaling for you and just a tip, it's a better practice to use `TextBlock` instead of `Label` where you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a viewbox

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Content="Text 1"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Horizontal and Vertical Alignment will have no effect there.

Comment: I was already testing it in visual studio, before your comment

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm not that big of a point glutton on such easy remedies.

Comment: Then why the complain?

Comment: It was teasing, not complaining, sheesh I think I'll leave this one be, too many seem to be far too involved in such a simple question.

Comment: You have one small error, the grid and column locations need to be moved up to the parent Viewbox `<Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">` It does not matter for the 0,0 location, but the code would fail if you tried to do the same with "Text 2"

Answer (score 1):

Change `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Center`
And leave `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` as `Stretch`, add a `<viewbox>` to make the `Text` stretch.

```
 <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Label.Content>
                <Viewbox  StretchDirection="Both">
                    <TextBlock Text="Text1" />
                </Viewbox>
            </Label.Content>
 </Label>
```

Comment: I took off my -1 and made it a +1, I don't know who did the other. (I also deleted my now non relevant comments)